# Select template or provide filename - which comes first

Tags: gui-design, design, dialog

Let's say I have a dialog used to create new files. I have to choose a template (Article, Task, Story) and provide a title and a filename (which can be automatically computed from the title). My question is which comes first in the dialog: the template selection or the title provision?

Looking at some software products (such as Eclipse or Jetbrains WebStorm), it seems that selecting the template comes first (but they use wizards, while I'd like to use a single dialog).

Here is an example of first selecting the template:

[image]

Should I change the order, and move the templates and the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name should be one of the last things to be selected. While I've never thought about it before this question, it makes perfect sense. Humans generally give names to things *after* they've been defined or identified, so that the name matches the definition. I have seen rare occasions in software where this isn't true (e.g. the image editor GIMP has an export option that presents an extra dialog based on the file name you choose), but those are usually more the exception than the rule. This is a widely adopted convention, so I'd suggest you leave the template first unless you have a valid reason for doing otherwise.